# does [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")] is used some where?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

I have made a web service that returns names of countries. What my web service returned was

```
<ArrayOfString>
               <string>Australia</string>
               <string>USA</string>
               <string>UK</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

Why we have `[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]` ?

I read it is on client side to distinguish nodes. This URL is also not location of web service.

Is it has any use practically ?

Answer (score 7):

Web Services use namespaces to distinguish their types from the types of other services.  `http://tempuri.org/` is a temporary (hence the name) namespace that should be replaced when put into a live environment.  Typically it would consist of a URI representing the source (i.e. your company's website URL) plus some other indicators to distinguish it from other services in your organization (e.g. `http://www.haansi.org/Companies`).

From [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webserviceattribute.aspx)

> An XML Web service should change its default XML namespace before it
>   is made public. Each XML Web service needs a unique XML namespace to
>   identify it so that client applications can distinguish it from other
>   services on the Web. http://tempuri.org/ is available for XML Web
>   services that are under development, but published XML Web services
>   should use a more permanent namespace.
>
> Your XML Web service should be identified by a XML namespace that you
>   control. For example, you could use your company's Internet domain
>   name as part of the XML namespace. Although many XML Web service XML
>   namespaces look like URLs, they need not point to an actual resource
>   on the Web. (XML Web service XML namespaces are URIs.) For XML Web
>   services created using ASP.NET, the default XML namespace can be
>   changed using Namespace property.

Answer (score 1):

The http://tempuri.org is just a placeholder. i.e. something text/markup/code that can be changed.

Comment: If you deploy it to a live site let's say www.mysite.com you would need to set the web service up and let's say MyWebService.asmx and to call it you would use http://www.mysite.com/MyWebService.asmx

Comment: As the web service is published you could allow other developers/sites to use this web service if you wanted to.